# When pushing to GitHub in IDEA, it needs input SSH password login

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have gen a key with `ssh-keygen` and added it to GitHub, but when I push to GitHub in idea, it needs input the SSH password to login.

[image: SSH password Login]

I want ask what the code is and why it needs me to input the password or whether there are solutions to solve this problem.

This problem has bothered me for a long time and thanks for you answer!

Comment: I have solved this problem. Like you said, ssh - t git@github.com It didn't work on my computer, so I did a search. This is because my computer lacks the ssh config file. After I added the relevant configuration file in the ssh folder according to the online tutorial, I can now successfully push and pull.  The configuration file contents are as follows：vim ~/.ssh/config
#fileContent:
Host github.com
identityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa #your private key file，need to be delete
Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
User git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if your [private key is encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129724): the password to enter would then be the passphrase you used when `ssh-keygen` the key.

If you are on Windows, as shown in [issue IDEA-90356](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90356/Built-In-SSH-does-not-use-private-key-for-git-pull), make sure your User environment variables include a `HOME` set to `%USERPROFILE%`.

Check also that `ssh -Tv git@github.com` works (meaning it ends with a welcome message: "`Hi username! You've successfully authenticated...`")

The [OP Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20074451/neil) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73834413/when-pushing-to-github-in-idea-it-needs-input-ssh-password-login/73835153#comment130388513_73835153)

> This is because my computer lacks the ssh config file.
> After I added the relevant configuration file in the ssh folder according to the online tutorial, I can now successfully push and pull.

Neil added the following `~/.ssh/config`

```
#fileContent: 
Host github.com 
  identityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa #your private key file，need to be delete
Host github.com 
  Hostname ssh.github.com 
  Port 443 
  User git
```

Comment: Thank you. I have solved this problem. Like you said, ssh - t git@github.com didn't work on my computer, so I did a search. This is because my computer lacks the ssh config file. After I added the relevant configuration file in the ssh folder according to the online tutorial, I can now successfully push and pull. Thank you again for your help

Comment: @Neil Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.